# Write a program Find that searches all files specified on the command line and prints out all lines containing a specified word

Tags: java

Write a program Find that searches all files specified on the command line and prints out all lines containing a specified word. For example, if you call

`java Find ring report.txt addres.txt Homework.java`

then the program might print

```
report.txt: has broken up an international ring of DVD bootleggers that
address.txt: Kris Kringle, North Pole
address.txt: Homer Simpson, Springfiled
Homework.java: String filename
```

---

First of all, I could not figure out how to store all the strings that are given in the commandline. Furthermore, my code only prints the part of the line *after* the found word (so for inst6ance it only prints out: of DVD bootleggers for the first file. How could I solve these issue? Could anyone please help me?

Here is my attempt:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class P6 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        for (int i = 0; i<args.length; i++)
        {
            String arg = args[i];
        }

        String input = "ring";

        File one = new File("report.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(one);
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            String een = in.next();

            if(een.matches(input))
            {
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You want to read the contents of the given file name in command line?

Comment: @msw Like your other comment, this comment is not all helpful. I tried stating the question in the best way I could and I wrote down my attempt. Since I'm new to this forum you could also just tell me what I should change and try to help me in finding an answer.l

Comment: @AchintyaJha Yes that's true. It should check all the programs from the command line for one specific word and then print out the whole line of that program in which that word appears.

Comment: @msw No I did not ask anyone to do my homework for me, since it is not even homework. I have problems with understanding an exercise and I ask specific questions about how it should be done. Your comments however are not helpful at all and are only trying to offend me. So please just ignore my questions in the future if you can't control yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String input = args[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" File  " + args[i]);
        File one = new File(args[i]);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(one);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            if (line.contains(input)) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is absolutely perfect! A very elegant solution. I highly appreciate your help :D!

Comment: You should also ensure that `args` has at least two elements and that the files specified on the command line exist.

Comment: I think while(in.hasNext()) should be while(in.hasNextLine()).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File one = new File("try.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(one);
    String input = "jha";
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String een = in.nextLine();

        if (een.contains(input)) {
            System.out.println(een);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code has no difference with mause's... but since mause upvote it, I cancelled my downvote.

Comment: @johnchen902 I upvote everyone who takes the effort to make a serious attempt at helping me. So therefore I upvoted him :)).